# Django - Type Error "is not subscriptable"

Tags: django, django-queryset, typeerror

I'm trying to create a list which consists of several calculations. next, the idea is to render it in a template.

This is what I have so far:

views.py :

```
def calculation(request, itemslug):

#All the Values ordered chronologically:  

values = Value.objects.filter(item__slug=itemslug).order_by('date')

dates = []
results =[]

#Create a list consisting of the dates

for value in values:
    a = value.date
    dates.append(a)

#Peform a calculation per date

for date in dates:

    latestvalue = Value.objects.filter(item__slug=itemslug).get(date=date)['amount']
    paidup = CashFlow.objects.filter(item__slug=itemslug).filter(date__lt=date).filter(type='cashin').aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))['sum']

    try:
       result = round(latestvalue/paidup * 100,2)
    except ZeroDivisionError :
       result = 0

    results.append(result)

return render(request, 'overview/detail.html',
    {
    'result':results,
    })
```

unfortunately I get the TypeError : 'Value object is not subscriptable'
+ might be the case there are some other errors in my code.. Many thanks to have a look !!

Thanks,

Comment: I'd try removing `[sum]` lookup for `paidup`. Something like this may work `CashFlow.objects.filter(....).aggregate(sum=Sum('amount')).sum`

Comment: its a queryset and not a dict

Comment: `['sum']` is fine (`aggregate()` returns a dictionary). But `['amount']` in the line above isn't, `get()` returns an object (`Value` here). So: `.amount`

Comment: yepla indeed !! Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simplifying it a bit:

```
    latestvalue = Value.objects.get(item__slug=itemslug, date=date).amount
    paidup = (CashFlow.objects
        .filter(item__slug=itemslug, date__lt=date, type='cashin')
        .aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))['sum'])
```